# Save Server Response from Retrofit2 Call in For-Each-Loop to file, database or new List / ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist, retrofit2

I am working on an Android app and receiving a Server response that I would like to either store in a Database or store in an ArrayList or List, in order to iterate through the values and compare the values to a scanned string; the logged output is the data that I need and want to save; unfortunately, my Java skills are not so good so that I don´t really know how to save this data in e.g. another List or an ArrayList.
The data that I need is there, hence I don´t really know how to store it...

This is the API-Call:

```
public static void writeItemsToDatabase(Context mContext, String basic) {

        //creating the itemApi interface
        ItemApi itemApi = retrofit.create(ItemApi.class);

        //making the call object
        Call<List<Item>> call = itemApi.checkItems(basic);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Item>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<List<Item>> call,
                                   @NonNull Response<List<Item>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccess()) {
                    List<Item> itemList;
                    itemList =  response.body();
                    int dataSize = response.body().size();
                    Log.d(TAGGG, String.valueOf(dataSize));
                    itemList.forEach(List -> Log.d(TAGGG, String.valueOf(List.getEan())));
                    itemList.forEach(List -> Log.d(TAGGG, String.valueOf(List.getNo())));

                    class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

                        // Runs in UI before background thread is called
                        @Override
                        protected void onPreExecute() {
                            super.onPreExecute();
                            // Do something like display a progress bar
                        }

                        // This is run in a background thread
                        @Override
                        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                            // Do something that takes a long time, for example:

                                try (DatabaseHandler erpDevelopment = new DatabaseHandler((XXXApp)
                                        mContext.getApplicationContext())) {
                                    itemList.stream().limit(4600).forEach(item -> {
                                        erpDevelopment.addItem(item);
                                        erpDevelopment.close();
                                    });
                                }
                                // Call this to update your progress

                            return "this string is passed to onPostExecute";
                        }

                        // This is called from background thread but runs in UI
                        @Override
                        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
                            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
                            // Do things like update the progress bar
                        }
                        // This runs in UI when background thread finishes
                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                            super.onPostExecute(result);
                            // Do things like hide the progress bar or change a TextView
                        }
                    }
                    new DownloadTask().execute();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Item>> call, Throwable t) {}
        });
        return;
    }
```

This is the Item Class:

```
package com.example.xxx;


import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Item {

    @SerializedName("no")
    private String no;

    @SerializedName("ean")
    private String ean;

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("itemgroupname")
    private String itemgroupname;

    @SerializedName("type")
    private String type;

    @SerializedName("destruction")
    private Boolean destruction;

    @SerializedName("archived")
    private Boolean archived;

    public Item(String no, String ean, String name, String type, String itemgroupname, Boolean destruction,
                Boolean archived) {
        this.no = no;
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.ean = ean;
        this.itemgroupname = itemgroupname;
        this.destruction = destruction;
        this.archived = archived;
    }

    public String getNo() {
        return no;
    }

    public void setNo(String no) {
        this.no = no;
    }

    public String getEan() {
        return ean;
    }

    public void setEan(String ean) {
        this.ean = ean;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getItemgroupname() {
        return itemgroupname;
    }

    public void setItemgroupname (String Itemgroupname) {
        this.itemgroupname = itemgroupname;
    }

    public boolean getDestruction() {
        return destruction;
    }

    public void setDestruction (Boolean Destruction ) {
        this.destruction = destruction;
    }

    public boolean getArchived() {
        return true;
    }

    public void setArchived (Boolean Archived ) {
        this.archived = archived;
    }
}
```

The output I want to store later maybe in a Database, but firstly in a File or in an ArrayList or List, is here:

```
  itemList.forEach(List -> Log.d(TAGGG, String.valueOf(List.getEan())));
  itemList.forEach(List -> Log.d(TAGGG, String.valueOf(List.getNo())));
```

it is precisely the data that I need, hence I don´t really know on how to "put" the data separately; I have a Database, but in the first place I would like to store it either in a file or in an ArrayList / List, depending on what makes more sense.

How do I do that?
How would a ForEach-Loop look like that saves all the data from List.getEan() and List.getNo() separately?
Any hints or help would be very much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please make the question more clear? Are you trying to save the Ean and No values in two separate lists?

Comment: @AmimulEhsanRahi: yes, I would like to save the Ean and No values in two separate lists.

Comment: Can you provide the item class also in your question?

Comment: @AmimulEhsanRahi: Added the Item Class to the Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok...first declare two lists of strings. One for the Ean and the another for the No.

```
List<String> EanList = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> NoList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Add them like this:

```
public static void writeItemsToDatabase(Context mContext, String basic) 
{
    List<String> EanList = new ArrayList<>();
     List<String> NoList = new ArrayList<>();
................
}
```

Then on the response being successful do this :

```
if(response.isSuccess())
{
    int dataSize = itemList.size();

    for(int i=0; i<dataSize; i++)
    {
         EanList.add(itemList.get(i).getEan());
         NoList.add(itemList.get(i).getNo());
     }
}
```

Here you just basically need to copy the values into two other lists of strings. After the running of for loop, your EanList and NoList will contain respective values.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That made my day